# Virtualenv, установил но не могу запустить(

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Установил виртуальную среду, все прошло успешно версия 16.7.8 в системе установлен python 3.7.4. После этого создал виртуальную среду virtualenv my_env командой, перешел в папку scripts запустил консоль из нее, что бы отобразился именно путь до папки
ввел activate пробовал так же вводить с source командой из оф. руководства, ничего не помогает, подскажите что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во первых, воспользуйтесь cmd а не Power Shell  - это уже должно помочь.
Если не сработает: проделайте шаги из этого туториала, но из обычной cmd https://tyapk.ru/blog/post/python-virtual-environment-windows

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, все сработало, а я голову ломал сидел. Правильно ли я понимаю что powershell лучше тогда совершенно не пользоваться?

Comment: Говорят, что в power shell более широкий функционал. Лично мне для работы всегда хватало cmd

Comment: Я обычно пользовался gitbush  в принципе не испытывал трудностей но для Frontend а с изучением python столкнулся с тем что не смог создать createsuperuser для DB, и от powershel как то не ожидал такого поведения, в офф руководстве написано так что про ослабление политики цифровой подписи для выполнения сценарием, я и эти шаги выполнил https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/ и результатов все равно не получил пока просто cmd не стал использовать , больше powershell не буду использовать